# gnome-online-account remembers my google password?

Tags: security, google, online-accounts

I just added my google account to gnome-online-account, assuming it'd use OAuth. I should mention I use two factor authentication.

I wrote in my google password + my verification key (but chose not to save it). After rebooting and reconnecting it said my account needed verification. I clicked the icon, clicked no "grant access", and got up my google login page, with the password apperantly already written in. I could click next and write in my verification code.

Is my password stored anywhere, or is authentication with a token still giving me a login page with the password apperantly written in when it needs to verify my account?

Comment: If you run seahorse, do you see that it stored your login?

Comment: Good idea to check it with seahorse. If you reply to that as an answer I'll accept it. It does store it, and it does not store a token, it stores the actual password. I'm replacing empathy today...

Comment: Okay, that was easier than I expected. FWIW, I believe the Gnome keyring is encrypted with your login password necessary to decrypt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use seahorse (the application) to see what login/passwords gnome is storing.

Comment: Leaving this as a comment and not as an answer - as an interesting note, I was not able to copy and paste my password from KeePassX into the prompt in Online Accounts for Google. After seeing this comment, I got the thought to paste the password into Seahorse, then try to paste from that instead. It worked!